# How to add a class to the variation out of stock in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to grey out the unavailable variations in my WordPress site. I've found this code that set the property to each unavailable option to "disabled"  and removes the class "enabled". The thing is that I do not need to set the option to disabled. Is there a way to just remove the class "enabled" or to add an "out-of-stock" class to each unavailable option?

The code that I am using inside my `functions.php` is the following:

```
/**
 * Disable out of stock variations
 * https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/826af31e1e3b6e8e5fc3c1004cc517c5c5ec25b1/includes/class-wc-product-variation.php
 * @return Boolean
 */
function wcbv_variation_is_active( $active, $variation ) {
 if( ! $variation->is_in_stock() ) {
 return false;
 }
 return $active;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_active', 'wcbv_variation_is_active', 10, 2 );
```